# Integrate interactive map with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I want to have an interactive map in an idlegame where you can click on a tile ([See screenshot](https://ibb.co/XXg8X7z)) and something should happen. I am trying to do so with an SVG and paths around the tile. Please tell me if there is a better way to implement something like this.

To my problem:
I have finally got my Map-Component to work containing the whole SVG. My two paths (polygon on image) are implemented as follows:

```
<g>
   <path id="Mine" fill="#000" fillOpacity="0.6" d="M987 204 L937 231 L937 282 L988 305 L1039 282 L1040 226" onClick={console.log('City clicked')} />
</g>
```

Problem: The onclick event is triggerd when the page is loading and not when the polygon is clicked on. Does react even support that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On click should be a function:
onClick={() => console.log('City clicked')}